# How can I count a pandas dataframe over duplications

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My initial dataframe is:

```
    Name        Info1        Info2
0  Name1  Name1-Info1  Name1-Info2
1  Name1  Name1-Info1  Name1-Info2
2  Name1  Name1-Info1  Name1-Info2
3  Name2  Name2-Info1  Name2-Info2
4  Name2  Name2-Info1  Name2-Info2
```

and i would like to return the number of repetitions of each row as such:

```
    Name        Info1        Info2  Count
0  Name1  Name1-Info1  Name1-Info2      3
1  Name2  Name2-Info1  Name2-Info2      2
```

How can I count a pandas dataframe over duplications?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
df.groupby(['Name', 'Info1', 'Info2']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:"count"})
```

Comment: You can rename inside reset-index, ``df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index(name='Count')``

Answer (score 4):

Given your example `df`:

```
    Name        Info1        Info2
0  Name1  Name1-Info1  Name1-Info2
1  Name1  Name1-Info1  Name1-Info2
2  Name1  Name1-Info1  Name1-Info2
3  Name2  Name1-Info2  Name1-Info2
4  Name2  Name1-Info2  Name1-Info2
```

The following:

```py
df.pivot_table(index=list(df), aggfunc='size')
```

Will return what you're after:

```
Name   Info1        Info2
Name1  Name1-Info1  Name1-Info2    3
Name2  Name1-Info2  Name1-Info2    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Add column `'count'` and do `df.groupby`

```
df['count'] = 1      
df.groupby(['Name', 'Info1', 'Info2'])['count'].sum().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
size = df.groupby('Name').size().tolist()
df = df.groupby('Name').tail(1).reset_index()
df['Count'] = size
```